# Powershell - Invoke-WebRequest with full content

Tags: powershell

Hi there quite a simple command :

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://x.x.x.x.:xxxx/databases?pageSize=8&start=0"`

I would like this to return me the full content for now I have something like this :

`Content           : [
                      "toto",
                      "toto",
                      "toto",
                      "toto",
                      "toto",
                      "toto",
                      "toto...`

Or do I get a full list ?

Thanks !

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di53i.png)

How can I have what is after `...`

Comment: What do you mean by "full list"? What the server is supposed to return?

Comment: Sorry it was not clear. well I have "..." so the list is not complete. 
I would like to get the full result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the web request results from JSON.  So, use something like this:

```
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://x.x.x.x.:xxxx/databases?pageSize=8&start=0"
$webRequest = $webRequest | ConvertFrom-Json
```

To see the `Content` property and expand it completely, use this:

```
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://x.x.x.x.:xxxx/databases?pageSize=8&start=0" | select Content | FL
```

Comment: Alternatively use `Invoke-RestMethod` and the results will be converted from JSON to a PowerShell object automatically.

Comment: @MarkWragg I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this guys. I did not know I could do that.
But I am not looking for formatting yet. Just to have the full list (some items are missing)

I put screenshot above thanks for your help !

Comment: @HouariSonnyTADJER See my edit in the above proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys.

Invoke-RestMethod was greate and I changed the pageSize value.
Before i had a 403.